# jquery make calculation for rows and show the result in the same row

Tags: jquery

I have my table like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" class="product-buying-price"></td>
    <td><input type="number" class="product-selling-price"></td>
    <td class="net-profit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" class="product-buying-price"></td>
    <td><input type="number" class="product-selling-price"></td>
    <td class="net-profit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" class="product-buying-price"></td>
    <td><input type="number" class="product-selling-price"></td>
    <td class="net-profit"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" class="product-buying-price"></td>
    <td><input type="number" class="product-selling-price"></td>
    <td class="net-profit"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can see that in this table I have input fields for input values. So there are 4 rows and in those have same 
class name. Like this I have more number of rows I have just used 4 rows here.
Now I want that when I make input some numbers in any rows then it should make a calculation and show the 
total after calculation in that row's net-profit class field.
so basically the calculation will do like this

```
Product selling price - Product buying price = net-profit
```

So can someone tell me how to do this for multiple rows and the same result will be shown in the same row after calculation?

```
$('body').on('keyup', '.product-buying-price, .product-selling-price', function() {
    var BuyingPrice = $('.product-buying-price').val();
    var SellingPrice = $('.product-selling-price').val();
    var Total = parseInt(SellingPrice)-parseInt(BuyingPrice);
    console.log(Total);
});
```

I have tried this but this one gives me result for one row only. How to get result for multiple rows?

Comment: What have you tried? We can help you when you are stuck somewhere, not to give you the entire code from scratch.

Comment: You have to provide any unique identifier for the resultant net-profit field.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.product-buying-price, .product-selling-price').on('blur', function(e) {

    // Get Parent ROW 
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var buying_pr = $('.product-buying-price', row), 
        selling_pr = $('.product-selling-price', row), 
        net_profit = $('.net-profit', row);

    buy_pr = parseFloat(buying_pr.val());
    sell_pr = parseFloat(selling_pr.val());

    if( ! isNaN(buy_pr) && !isNaN(sell_pr) ) {
        net_profit.text( ( sell_pr - buy_pr ).toFixed(2) );
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/dtahjbxm/)**

If you are creating dynamic tr with inputs then use:

```
$('body').on('blur', '.product-buying-price, .product-selling-price', function(e) {
```